# Hiding secret/publishable Stripe API keys in .env file, not working

Tags: reactjs, silverstripe, stripe-payments

How do I hide my secret/publishable Stripe API keys via the .env file? It looks like I'm following the instructions correctly, but it's not working. When I directly list the keys, it works, but not when passing through the .env file.

Below is my .env file

**.env**

```
REACT_APP_STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY='pk_test_***hidden, but full key displayed here in my original code***'
REACT_APP_STRIPE_SECRET_KEY='sk_test_***hidden, but full key displayed here in my original code***'
```

**stripe.js (Secret Key)**

```
const stripe = require('stripe')(process.env.REACT_APP_STRIPE_SECRET_KEY);

async function postCharge(req, res) {
  try {
    const { amount, source, receipt_email, title, address, customerName } = req.body;

    const { data } = await stripe.customers.list({ email: receipt_email });
    const customer = data.length ? data.find((c) => c.email === receipt_email) : null;

    let nCustomer;
    if (customer && customer.id) {
      nCustomer = await stripe.customers.update(customer.id, {
        default_source: customer.default_source,
      });
    } else {
      nCustomer = await stripe.customers.create({
        email: receipt_email,
        source,
        name: customerName,
        address,
      });
    }

    const charge = await stripe.charges.create({
      amount,
      currency: 'usd',
      source,
      receipt_email,
      description: `Product: ${title}`,
      customer: nCustomer.id,
    });

    if (!charge) throw new Error('charge unsuccessful');

    res.status(200).json({
      message: 'charge posted successfully',
      charge,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({
      message: error.message,
    });
  }
}

module.exports = postCharge;
```

**PaymentForm (Publishable Key)**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Typography, Button, Divider } from '@material-ui/core';
import {
  Elements,
  CardElement,
  ElementsConsumer,
  useStripe,
  useElements,
} from '@stripe/react-stripe-js';
import { loadStripe } from '@stripe/stripe-js';
import axios from 'axios';

import { getTotal } from '../../helpers/helperTools';


import Review from './Review';

const stripePromise = loadStripe(process.env.REACT_APP_STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY);

const CheckoutForm = ({ shippingData, backStep, nextStep, setQty }) => {
  const stripe = useStripe();
  const elements = useElements();
  const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (!stripe || !elements) {
      return;
    }

    const storageItems = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('product'));
    const products = storageItems || [];

    const totalPrice = getTotal(products);
    let productTitle = '';

    products.map((item, index) => {
      productTitle = `${productTitle} | ${item.title}`;
    });

    const cardElement = elements.getElement(CardElement);
    // Instead of token we need to attach source here
    // because source has more payments options available
    const { error, source } = await stripe.createSource(cardElement);
    console.log(error, source);
    const order = await axios.post('http://localhost:7000/api/stripe/charge', {
      amount: totalPrice * 100,
      source: source.id,
      receipt_email: shippingData.email,
      title: productTitle,
      customerName: `${shippingData.firstName} ${shippingData.lastName}`,
      address: {
        city: shippingData.City,
        country: shippingData.shippingCountry,
        line1: shippingData.address1,
        postal_code: shippingData.ZIP,
        state: shippingData.shippingState,
      },
    });

    if (error) {
      console.log('[error]', error);
    } else {
      console.log('[PaymentMethod]', order);
      localStorage.setItem('product', JSON.stringify([]));
      nextStep();
      setQty({quantity: 0});
    }
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <CardElement
        options={{
          style: {
            base: {
              fontSize: '16px',
              color: '#424770',
              '::placeholder': {
                color: '#aab7c4',
              },
            },
            invalid: {
              color: '#9e2146',
            },
          },
        }}
      />
      <div style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'space-between' }}>
        <Button variant='outlined' onClick={backStep}>
          Back
        </Button>
        <Button type='submit' variant='contained' disabled={!stripe} color='primary'>
          Pay
        </Button>
      </div>
    </form>
  );
};

function PaymentForm({ shippingData, backStep, nextStep, setQty }) {
  return (
    <Elements stripe={stripePromise}>
      <Review />
      <br />
      <br />
      <CheckoutForm shippingData={shippingData} nextStep={nextStep} backStep={backStep} setQty={setQty} />
    </Elements>
  );
}

export default PaymentForm;
```

Below is a screenshot of my file structure:
[image: rt]

Comment: Put `require('dotenv').config();` above `const stripe = require('stripe')(process.env.REACT_APP_STRIPE_SECRET_KEY);` If you don't have Dotenv, run `npm i dotenv`

Comment: I added require('dotenv').config(); and installed dotenv and it's still not working unfortunately

Comment: Have you restarted the app after install?

Comment: yes, i restarted my pc even

Comment: Can you change those singe quotes to double quotes. e.g. `REACT_APP_STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY="pk_test_..."`

Comment: updated, still doesn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because it looks for environment variables on your computer.
To use variables from .env file use libraries like dotenv(https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv)

The usage of this lib is pretty simple, just provide in your main server.js file the next line:

```
require('dotenv').config();
```

Comment: I added require('dotenv').config(); at the top of the stripe.js file and then installed dotenv (npm install dotenv). I then restarted my project and it's still not working unfortunately, is there something else I can troubleshoot?

Comment: i see the problem, your .env file should be on the same level in folder structure as the file where you include require('dotenv').config();

So there is 2 options:
1. Move your .env file into the /server/src folder
2. Move server.js on the top level, and declare require('dotenv').config() there

Comment: or you cantry to pass the "path" parameter into config oprions:
require('dotenv').config({ path: '../../.env' })

Comment: You are correct, I needed to move .env file on same level in the folder structure, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Remove single quotes from .env file variables values:

`REACT_APP_STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY=pk_test_***hidden, but full key displayed here in my original code***

REACT_APP_STRIPE_SECRET_KEY=sk_test_***hidden, but full key displayed here in my original code***`

Also install dot-env package in your machine if it still doesn't work. Happened with me when i was having same issue with my app deployed in google cloud

Comment: I removed all single quotes and ran: npm install dotenv. Still not working for some reason...

Answer (score 0):

```
const Stripe = require("stripe);
exports.function = async ()=>{
    const stripe = Stripe(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY);
}
```

Comment: call Stripe(STRIPE_SECRET) from inside of export function.

Comment: Please [edit] your answer instead of commenting. Also, your code has syntax errors.